# Using the standard error of the difference between means (s.e.d.m.) as opposed to the standard deviation

Tags: self-study, variance

I'm trying to teach myself an intuitive understanding of basic statistics and have encountered the following problem in a textbook:

**Q:** Seven observers were shown five dishes containing mustard seeds. The observers were asked to estimate the number in each dish. The mean guesses per observer across al five dishes were: 183.2, 149.0, 154.0, 167.2, 187.2, 158.0, and 143.0. The actual number of seeds in each dish was 161. What is the minimum increased number of seeds that you might expect a new observer to be able to discriminate from 161 seeds in five guesses?

My attempt at an answer:

1. True mean of the sample = (183 + 149 + 154 + 167 + 187 + 158 + 143)
   / 7 = **163**
2. The variance (of means of 5 guesses per observer) =  [(183 - 163)² +
   (149 - 163)² + (154 - 163)² + (167 - 163)² + (187 - 163)² + (158 -
   163)² + (143 - 163)²] / 6 = **286**
3. Therefore, the standard error = √286 = **16.9**
4. So, any observer should be able to distinguish between 163 and (163 + (2 x 16.9)) = **196.8** seeds in a mean of five guesses.

However, the textbook says that I should first calculate the standard error of the difference between two means (s.e.d.m.) by doubling the variance, leading to a s.e.d.m. of **23.9** and a minimum of **210.8** seeds.

I do not understand why I should use the s.e.d.m. here. As I see it, you can rephrase the question - it is asking the minimum mean guess a new observer would have to make to conclude that his sample does not come from the same distribution as the other seven guesses. Therefore, he would have to estimate a mean number of seeds that is higher than twice the standard error of the sample to notice a significant difference.

I would be very grateful for any help on this question!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.